# My ajax cart doesn't refresh after applying coupon code so my free product doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have to refresh the actual page for it to appear. Is there a way to simple have it refresh and appear after the coupon code is loaded?

```
  if ($codeLength) {
            if ($isCodeLengthValid && $couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                $result['current_coupon'] = $couponCode;
                $msg = $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($couponCode));
                $result = $this -> _prepareSuccessResponse($msg,$result);
            }
```

As soon as the $msg fires it should populate the item too in the minicart.

```
coupon: function (apply) {
        this.cacheElements();
        this.elLoader.show();

        var coupon_code = this._getCouponInput().getValue();

        new Ajax.Request(this.actionUrl.coupon, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {coupon_code: coupon_code, apply: apply},
            onSuccess: function (transport) {
                var response = transport.responseText;
                if (response.isJSON()) {
                    response = response.evalJSON();

                    if (response.success == 1) {
                        this.showMessageSuccess(response.message);
                    } else {
                        this.showMessageError(response.message);
                    }
                    this.elCoupon.update(response.coupon);
                }
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
```

ajax_cart.js

```
  _hangEventListenerOnCoupon: function() {
        //listener on 'apply' button
        var couponWrapperId = '';
        var couponFormId    = '';

        switch(this.type) {
            case this.ajaxCartType:
                couponWrapperId = this.tmAjaxCouponWrapperId;
                couponFormId    = this.ajaxCartCouponFormId;
                break;
            case this.minicartType:
                couponWrapperId = this.minicartCouponWrapperId;
                couponFormId    = this.minicartCouponFormId;
                break;
        }

        Event.observe($(couponFormId), 'submit', this._couponFormFireApplyClick.bindAsEventListener(this, couponFormId));
        Event.observe($(couponWrapperId).down(this.ajaxCartApplyCouponClass), 'click', this._submitCouponForm.bindAsEventListener(this));
        //listener on 'cancel' button
        var couponCancelLink = $$('#'+couponWrapperId+' '+this.ajaxCartCancelCouponClass);

        if (typeof couponCancelLink !== 'undefined') {
            couponCancelLink.each(function(link){
                Event.observe(link, 'click', this._cancelCoupon.bindAsEventListener(this));
            }.bind(this));
        }
        this.mini_cart_resize();
    },

    _couponFormFireApplyClick: function(event, couponFormId) {
        //prevent default
        Event.stop(event);
        var applyButton = $(couponFormId).down(this.ajaxCartApplyCouponClass);
        //fire click event
        applyButton.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    },
```